# How can I correctly type a set and implement it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want a typing for an object that replicates a set. For instance, I wish to have the transaction id as a key and the transaction details as the value. In my attempt to do so, I typed it as such,

```
type TransactionDetail = {
  [key: TransactionId]: TransactionDetails;
};
```

This will be a prop type for my function,

```
const handleTransctcionSync = (transaction: TransactionDetail, isChecked: boolean) => {
}
```

However, I was having a tough time figuring out how to pass the prop to this function. I tried doing this but is not accepted.

```
handleTransactionDataSync({id: transactionDetails}, !isChecked);
```

Any guidance on how to achieve this?

Comment: In the code where you are trying to use it there is only an `id` property, it doesn't appear to be anything dynamic. In other words, the type would be `type TransactionDetail = { id: TransactionDetails; };` according to the usage. Or did you mean to do something more along the lines of `handleTransactionDataSync({ [id]: transactionDetails }, !isChecked); `?

Comment: What is the type definition for `TransactionId`? Did you mean to use `id` as a variable key (where the key is the value of a variable called `id`, instead of the key being the string `"id"`)

Comment: sorry, I missed providing that information. The id is 

const id: TransactionId = transactionDetails.id;

I wish the key to be the id of the transaction which is being fetched as shown above. This key should have a value of the transactionDetails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the id is `const id: TransactionId = transactionDetails.id;` then the `id` should be used as a dynamic object key instead of the literal key `"id"`.

Example:

```
const id: TransactionId = transactionDetails.id;

...

handleTransactionDataSync({ [id]: transactionDetails }, !isChecked);
```

or more simply:

```
handleTransactionDataSync(
  { [transactionDetails.id]: transactionDetails },
  !isChecked,
);
```

It seems the transaction id is a string type:

```
type TransactionDetail = {
  [key: string]: TransactionDetails;
};
```

If `transactionDetails` is missing properties from `TransactionDetails` then they either need to be added to `transactionDetails` or made optional.

```
interface TransactionDetails {
  // ...the required properties

  // then optional properties
  displayedType?: ....,
  errors?: ....,
  hasNoGains?: ....,
  icon?: ....,
  // ...and 7 more optional
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to implement it

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: TransactionDetails; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransactionDetails'.
  Type '{ [x: string]: TransactionDetails; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TransactionDetails': displayedType, errors, hasNoGains, icon, and 7 more
```

Comment: I tried switching the key to a string, but am still getting a similar error.

Comment: @TanDev Please share all the type declarations being used and an example `transactionDetails` object so it's clear what the code is trying to define and what is being assigned.

Comment: Hey i was able to resolve the issue. I had a wrong typing for transactions at one place

Comment: @TanDev Great to hear and glad to help. Cheers and good luck!